# Html 5 Canvas image Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dom-events

I want to create a image gallery using Html 5 Canvas and when I hover a image, it must grow and change opacity. In addition to image selectable and draggable? 
How can I do this? Any ideas?

Comment: [How to import images in a `canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images) and [how to create a gallery using `canvas`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2011/01/26/creating_2d00_a_2d00_picture_2d00_gallery_2d00_with_2d00_html5_2d00_canvas.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Well sir, first try to code anything and then come to ask for assistance with particular problem. For now it looks like you have no clue about subject and not even tried. I can anwser a question like `how to manipulate opacity in canvas`, `how to implement drag and drop`, `etc...`

but NOT `I need someone to implement my whole idea for me`

I should also point out that Canvas isn't probably the best technology for this task (in the meaning of both performance and implementation difficulty).

If you insist, you will have to rewrite all functionality which is already easily accessible with DOM and libraries like jQuery.